# Does your internet provider see that you're using TOR?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I hope this doesn't sound like a stupid question but can your internet service provider see that you're using TOR? I don't want the police to show up at my door asking me why I was searching for gifts cards at a discounted price lol. If you connect to VPN before loading up TOR would you ISP see that you connected to a VPN?

- Disclaimer: I have not bought anything with TOR or plan to. This is a hypothetical question that is for educational purposes.

Comment: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https is a good site for playing around and finding out who will see what.

Comment: further more it is [not recommended to use VPNs for anonymity resp. in conjunction with Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN) because you are just exchanging the trusted party (ISP) with another one (VPN). - if you want to hide the fact that you are using Tor you should [use bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html#UsingBridges) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using bridges like OBFS can protect your TOR connection from ISPs however youcan use VPN before TOR and TOR before VPN.

If you use VPN to access TOR, ISP only sees the VPN connection but with the TOR traffic pattern, therefore I suggest using OBFS when you're using VPN.

If you use TOR to access VPN, ISP will know that you're using TOR (as mentioned, use OBFS) and you can access sites like Google which ban TOR traffic. More information can be found in https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-again/.